# Where is the Folder for shared library in a django project

Tags: django, boost-python

I am working on a python/django project which calls a C++ shared library. I am using boost_python C++ library.
It works fine: I can call C++ methods from python interpreter. I can also call this methods from my django project. But i am wondering something: Where is the best folder for my C++ shared library ?
I actually put this binary shared library in django app folder (same folder as view.py). It works but i think this is ugly... Is there a specific folder for shared library in django directory structure ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

put them to `$PROJECT_HOME/lib` just like a normal package

Comment: I have tried but then i cannot import my module. It says me No module named xxxx. I tried to import like lib.mylib. It does not work...

Comment: is there a `__init__.py` file in your lib folder?

Comment: This library is written in C++. It is an elf shared library. So i don not think this __init__.py is required. What should i put in int ?